# Is the "void" keyword on a void function optional? Or is there a type-o in Jon Skeet's book?

Tags: c#

The example I'm scratching my head over is *C# In Depth, 3rd Edition, pg. 85, Listing 3.9*, which starts out like

```
public class Outer<T>
{
    public class Inner<U,V>
    {
        static Inner()
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Outer<{0}>.Inner<{1},{2}>",
                              typeof(T).Name,
                              typeof(U).Name,
                              typeof(V).Name);
        }
        public static void DummyMethod() { }
    }
}
```

What is the return value of `Inner`? Is it left unspecified and interpreted as `void`?

Comment: `Inner()` is the constructor. Here...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx

Comment: Did you try it? It's a simple copy/paste.

Comment: You're not Mr. Ballmer, and Mr. Skeet wouldn't make (this kind of) mistake

Comment: Whoops, I knew that. My bad.

Comment: And it must be noted that constructors must have same name as their class other wise it will not be a constructor and it will not compile

Comment: There is a typo in your question. It's Jon Skeet, not 'John' Skeet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Inner()` doesn't return anything.  It's the [static constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

You wouldn't actually invoke that method directly.  It'll be invoked automatically by the framework when it needs to be.

Answer (score 2):

Inner() is the constructor so its type is its self. The type void means its a method that doesn't return anything but you will always need to specify it for any void methods.